# Customized JTable look

Tags: java, swing, jtable, look-and-feel

I want to create a JTable with few columns which has JButtons on it. I can create JCheckBoxes and also JComboBoxes in the JTable cells but not the JButtons. How do i do this ?

Comment: See [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/); the author will be along shortly. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project, this is how I did it for a 4-row table with 3 columns where the first column has `JToggleButton` in every row:

The necessary objects...

```
private JTable table1;
private DefaultTableModel table1Model;
private JScrollPane scrollPane1;
String[] columnName = {"Button", "Boolean", "Int" };
```

and under the code where we create the table...

```
    {
        JToggleButton[] jTableButton = new JToggleButton[] { new JToggleButton("one"), new JToggleButton("two"), new JToggleButton("three"), new JToggleButton("four")};
        table1Model =
            new DefaultTableModel(
                    new Object[][] { { jTableButton[0], false, 1 },
                                     { jTableButton[1], false, 1 },
                                     { jTableButton[2], false, 1 },
                                     { jTableButton[3], false, 1 }},
                                     columnName);

        table1 = new JTable(table1Model){
            /**
             *
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
                int value = (Integer) table1Model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 2);

                String blueColor = Color.BLUE;
                String redColor = Color.RED;
                String selectedColor = Color.GREEN;

                String colorValue = selectedColor;

                if ( value > 0) {
                    colorValue = blueColor; //blue
                }
                else {
                    colorValue = redColor; //red
                }

                return !colorValue.equals(redColor); // Disallow the editing of red cell
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int c) {
                return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
            }

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,int rowIndex, int vColIndex)
            {
                int value = (Integer) table1Model.getValueAt(rowIndex, 2);

                String blueColor = Color.BLUE;
                String redColor = Color.RED;
                String selectedColor = Color.GREEN;

                String colorValue = selectedColor;

                if ( value > 0) {
                    colorValue = blueColor; //blue
                }
                else {
                    colorValue = redColor; //red
                }

                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, vColIndex);
                if (!isCellSelected(rowIndex, vColIndex))
                {

                    if (vColIndex != 0 ) {
                        c.setEnabled(!colorValue.equals(redColor));
                    }
                    else {
                        c.setEnabled(!colorValue.equals(redColor));

                        if (colorValue.equals(redColor))
                            c.setBackground(Color.decode(colorValue));
                    }

                    if (c instanceof JToggleButton && vColIndex == 0){
                        JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton) c;
                        button.setToolTipText(((JToggleButton) c).getText());
                    }

                    if (   Color.decode(colorValue).getRed() >= 224
                            && Color.decode(colorValue).getGreen() >= 224
                            && Color.decode(colorValue).getBlue() >= 224){

                        c.setForeground(Color.gray);

                    }
                    else {

                        c.setForeground(Color.white);
                    }
                }
                return c;
            }

        };

        scrollPane1.setViewportView(table1);
        table1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(187,290));
        table1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI",0,14));
        table1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new JToggleButtonRenderer());
    }
```

**JToggleButtonRenderer.java**

```
class JToggleButtonRenderer extends JToggleButton implements TableCellRenderer {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        if (isSelected) {
            // cell (and perhaps other cells) are selected
        }

        if (hasFocus) {
            // this cell is the anchor and the table has the focus
        }

        return (Component) value;
    }

    // The following methods override the defaults for performance reasons

    @Override
    public void validate() {}

    @Override
    public void revalidate() {}

    @Override
    protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {}

    @Override
    public void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, boolean oldValue, boolean newValue) {}  
}
```

As you can see, the important part is the table model, `table1Model`

To add a new row...

```
//id is something you want put on the button text
table1Model.addRow(new Object[] { new JToggleButton(id), false, 1} );
```

**edited:**

Added missing JToggleButton cell renderer

Comment: wrong answer for several reasons: a) never-ever store components in the model! The model is for data which is rendered by a component as provided by the renderer b) never-ever subclass a JTable (or any other JSomething) for application needs, especially not for doing weird hard-coded value-to-visual properties mapping