# add jcheckBox to Jtable using GUI

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

after searching in google and stackoverflow and going over some answers i'm still stuck with this problem.

i've jtable and i'm filling it from database(derpy-JDBC).
**i want add check box to my jtable using GUI**..i have change column type to boolean and add these lines

```
JCheckBox checkBox = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
jTable1.getColumn("status").setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(checkBox));
```

but it doesn't work correctly. 
this my try

```
public class showp1 extends javax.swing.JFrame implements  ActionListener  {

    /** Creates new form showp1 */
    public showp1() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jButton1.addActionListener(this);
        jButton2.addActionListener(this);
      jTextField1.addActionListener(this);

    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "id", "area", "location", "status"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        jButton2.setText("jButton2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 320, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addGap(73, 73, 73)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addGap(166, 166, 166))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 375, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED))))
                .addGap(10, 10, 10))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 23, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 155, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(64, 64, 64))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  

       myDbConnection dbconnect;
        // TODO add your handling code here:


               ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {

         dbconnect = new myDbConnection();
            ResultSet resultSet =null;
            resultSet = dbconnect.excuteQuery("SELECT id, area,location, status1 FROM pledges ");



                while (resultSet.next()){
                   list.add(resultSet.getString(1));
                    list.add(resultSet.getString(2));
                    list.add(resultSet.getString(3));
                    list.add(resultSet.getString(4));
                }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        Object[][] record;

        int myListCount = list.size()/4;
        record = new Object[myListCount][4];
        int count = 1;
       // JCheckBox checkBox = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        for (int ii = 1; ii<=myListCount;ii++) {
            for(int i=1;i<=4;i++){
                record[ii-1][i-1] = list.get(count-1);
                count++;

            }

        }
        //TableColumnModel columnModel = jTable1.getColumnModel();
         //columnModel.getColumn(3).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(checkBox));

        jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(record, new String[]{"id", "area", "location","status1"}) {
        @Override
     public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (getColumnName(columnIndex).equals("status1")) {
           return Boolean.class;
        }
        return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
     }
  });


 public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new showp1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
} }
```

sorry for this awful code^^"
thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, try to check my post on how to add `JToggleButton` to each row in a `JTable`. In my sample code, I put one column with a boolean type.. It tells you that you don't need to specifically render `jCheckBox` if you want to have `JCheckBox` on each row for column(s) with a boolean type since, by default, `DefaultTableModel` will automatically render such column(s) as `JCheckBox` class model http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334444/customized-jtable-look/5334562#5334562

Comment: @eee while your example is creative - it's completely against Swinging winds ;-)

Comment: please learn and use java naming conventions

Answer (score 2):

Read the [Oracle Swing JTable tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and you'll see that you don't need to use a cell renderer or editor directly, that all you need to do is to return the correct column class of Boolean.class, and Swing will supply the correct renderer and editor for you. This is done by overriding the TableModel's getColumnClass(int column) method.

e.g.,

```
  jTable1.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(record, new String[]{"id", "area", "location",
     "status1"}) {
     @Override
     public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (getColumnName(columnIndex).equals("status1")) {
           return Boolean.class;
        }
        return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
     }
  });
```

Note that for this to work record needs to be a 2-dimensional array of Object[][], not of String[][], and the status1 column must hold Boolean data, not String data, but that should be easy enough for you to fix when you are populating the record array in your nested for loops.

Comment: i updated the code in my question and did every thing as you said(change record to object & status1 column hold Boolean data) but still showing to me error message

Comment: please not the name of the column in database is "status1" and in Jtable is "status" and type of this column in jtable is boolean and in database is integer

Comment: @mbasleem: Add an addendum to your question showing your latest attempt at your code solution using my idea. Preferable would be if you could post a small compilable program that shows your attempt, one we could run without need to use a database -- an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)

Comment: i'm Afraid that i can't do what you said because i don't know how to do it without database and also i want it with database..but any way i've updated the question and put the whole code..i hope its clear now..thanks for your care

Comment: Your current code is not "complete" as it is missing many variable declarations and methods, but regardless, we will be able to better help you with a small *compilable and runnable* sample program. I realize that you want to use a database in your main program, but it's not that difficult to simulate this with a simple ArrayList or 2-dimensional array of test data.  If you've already solved your problem, then please ignore my advice, but if you want the best chances of getting our help fast, I strongly urge you to create an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) (please see the link).